# Using dependency property default value as binding source

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, viewmodel, dependency-properties

Having to work with a legacy silverlight application I ran into a strange piece of code. The viewmodel has a List dependency property as binding source for the grid. This DP has a default value, an other List that is used globally in the app. This is used to easily share entity data between different parts of the application.

```
DependencyProperty MyEntitiesProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyEntities", typeof(List<Entity>), typeof(...), new PropertyMetadata(Global.Entities));
```

Now, when the list is changed (on user actions), the global list is repopulated from database but MyEntities is never set explicitly. This does not work: the grid (the binding target) never changes. So its a wrong solution.

I speculate that the idea behind all this could have been been the following: if you have a DP with a given value and you never set a local value for it then the effective value of the DP will be the default value. If the 'underlying' default value is changed, the changes are reflected in the effective value.

If it worked, it was a nice way of sharing data between independent viewmodels without fiddling with property change events and such.

What is wrong here? Is it a big misunderstanding of how DPs work or the idea was ok and some implementation details were missed?

Please comment if something is not clear.

Comment: You wrote "the global list is repopulated from database", and I read this as "the list instance stays the same, only the items are removed and the updated items are added again". Am I wrong here? Because there is a big difference if the list instance is the same over the application lifetime or if new list instances are created.

Comment: Martin, I understand the difference between adding/removing items and setting a new item reference. How does it affect the binding behaviour of DPs? In the actual code, a new list is created.

Comment: Your problem solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, taking also your comment into account, it is a big misunderstanding of how DPs work. Let me explain:

Setting a globally known list as the default value of *MyEntities* might not be a pattern I recommend, but is technically not faulty and can be done to share a list. *MyEntities* now holds a reference to this very list.

If you now replace the global list with a new list instance, the old instance does not cease to exist. Your property *MyEntities* still holds a reference to the old list. The value of a DP is only updated automatically if it is bound via `Binding` to either an ordinary property that is wired with the `INotifyPropertyChanged` mechanism or another DP.

Setting a default value happens neither via a `Binding` to an ordinary property nor via a `Binding` to another DP, it is just a plain old object reference.

I can think of several ways to correct the situation:

**First solution**

If the global list implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` (e.g. [ObservableCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), [DependencyObjectCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee652772%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)) you can - instead of creating a new list instance - just delete the old items from the list and add the new items. The views that have a reference to the list will perform an update as soon as they receive the associated `CollectionChanged` event.

**Second solution**

Make sure the `Global.Entities` list is available and always up-to-date as a public property (wired with `INotifyPropertyChanged`) on the `DataContext` of the root view. Now when you want a nested view somewhere deep down inside the UI tree to be connected to this `Global.Entities` list you can bind it to the root view's DataContext' public list property.

```
<MyRootView>
    ... nested views spread across multiple files ...
    <MyNestedEntitiesListDisplay
        MyEntities="{Binding
            Path=DataConext.GlobalEntities,
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=MyRootView}}"/>
```